# Take chunks of data from pandas df based on repeated values ranges in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to select data from the pandas dataframe based on the repeated range of values in a particular column. For example, I've df below.

```
range_col col1 col2
  1        a   b
  2        c   d
  3        e   f
  1        m   n
  2        o   p
  3        r   s
  1        e   f
  2        j   k
  3        l   m
```

In above df, I would like to iterate thru chunk of data by selecting ranges `1 2 3` from `range_col`. So first chunk will be

```
range_col col1 col2
  1        a   b
  2        c   d
  3        e   f
```

Second will be

```
range_col col1 col2
  1        m   n
  2        o   p
  3        r   s
```

etc...

How can I iterate on df like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
for _, group in df.groupby(df['range_col'] - df.index, sort=False):
    print(group)
    print()
```

**Output**

```
    range_col col1 col2
0          1    a    b
1          2    c    d
2          3    e    f

   range_col col1 col2
3          1    m    n
4          2    o    p
5          3    r    s

   range_col col1 col2
6          1    e    f
7          2    j    k
8          3    l    m
```

This is based on an old recipe from itertools, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#examples).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) (see **Detail** of `groups`) to create groups using [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
groups=(df['range_col']==df['range_col'].min()).cumsum()
for i,group in df.groupby(groups):
    print(group)
    print('-'*20)
```

---

**Output:**

```
       range_col col1 col2
0          1    a    b
1          2    c    d
2          3    e    f
--------------------
   range_col col1 col2
3          1    m    n
4          2    o    p
5          3    r    s
--------------------
   range_col col1 col2
6          1    e    f
7          2    j    k
8          3    l    m
--------------------
```

**Detail:**

```
print(groups)
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
Name: range_col, dtype: int64
```

---

**You could save the dataframes in a dict:**

```
groups=(df['range_col']==df['range_col'].min()).cumsum()
dfn={i:group for i,group in df.groupby(groups)}

for n in dfn:
    print(f'df[{n}]')
    print(dfn[n])
    print('-'*20)

df[1]
   range_col col1 col2
0          1    a    b
1          2    c    d
2          3    e    f
--------------------
df[2]
   range_col col1 col2
3          1    m    n
4          2    o    p
5          3    r    s
--------------------
df[3]
   range_col col1 col2
6          1    e    f
7          2    j    k
8          3    l    m
--------------------
```